# Do SQL Server disabled databases cause any usage concerns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SaaS e-commerce app. When clients stop using the service I disable their SQL Server Database and User Account rather than delete them.

Do these *disabled* databases cause any concerns related to stress on the server or SQL Server limitations on databases? For example is the any type of overhead just leaving them there? *I have our backup tasks setup to **not** make backups for disabled databases.*

I use SQL Server 2008 Web Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll see much overhead except for system processes that enumerate databases for certain tasks. E.g. trace the server and expand the databases node in Management Studio - I bet you see a *LOT* more activity on the system when there are 50 active databases and 500 disabled databases compared to just 50 active databases.

Once a client has left, I would typically make a final backup of the database, mark the database as offline, wait 30 days in case they make any post-requests for data or reports, then drop the database once the backup is off-site (or whatever your "really backed up" status means).